# Android show MainActivity through bottomsheet interaction

Tags: android

i have created a bottomsheet layout in my MainActivity.

In my bottomsheetlistener im calling different fragments to show different content like this:

```
  private BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener
        = new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.camera:

            case R.id.story:
                setTitle("Story"); //this will set title of Action Bar
                StoryFragment fragment1 = new StoryFragment();
                FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction1 = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                fragmentTransaction1.addToBackStack(null);//create first framelayout with id fram in the activity where fragments will be displayed

                fragmentTransaction1.replace(R.id.fram, fragment1, "Fragment One");  //create first framelayout with id fram in the activity where fragments will be displayed
                fragmentTransaction1.commit();

                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
};
```

My MainActivity should interact like a Fragment because inside my MainActivity i have different libraries which doesnt work inside a fragment. So how can i disable the current fragment to show my activity-main layout?
Thanks

Comment: `My MainActivity should interact like a Fragment` it doesn't seem like you're using Activities correctly... An Activity should "house" the fragments. Your `activity-main` is a minimal layout file which contains a ToolBar, FrameLayout and BottomBar. That's it.

Comment: but i have to run inside my activity a camera library which doesnt work smooth in a fragment enviroment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some solutions:

1. From activityWithFragments just send intent to anotherActivity which include all features you want to show. In instagram when the list of fragments is over next slide is opening new activity with camera. Or it can be after click
2. Make container for fragments not full screen and leave some space for activity behind so on the same screen you could use fragments and at the same time activity which holds that fragments.
3. If it is so "custom-custom" you can change your bottom navigation on your custom menu and it will give you 100% flexibility which navigationMenu couldnt give to you